# Mongodb group by values and count the number of occurence

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to count how many times does a particular value occur in a collection.

```json
{
  _id:1,
  field1: value,
  field2: A,
}

{
  _id:2,
  field1: value,
  field2: A,
}

{
  _id:3,
  field1: value,
  field2: C,
}

{
  _id:4,
  field1: value,
  field2: B,
}
```

what I want is to count how many times A occurs, B occurs and C occurs and return the count.

The output I want

```json
{
  A: 2,
  B: 1,
  C: 1,
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add example documents and expected output?

Comment: @NeNaD Please check the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$facet` in an aggregate pipeline like this:

- `$facet` create "three ways" where in each one filter the values by desired key (A, B or C).
- Then in a `$project` stage you can get the `$size` of the matched values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "first": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "field2": "A"
          }
        }
      ],
      "second": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "field2": "B"
          }
        }
      ],
      "third": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "field2": "C"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "A": {
        "$size": "$first"
      },
      "B": {
        "$size": "$second"
      },
      "C": {
        "$size": "$third"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aj3SwZ9vz93)

Comment: Hi, I think this can be done much more efficient with `$group` stage than 3 separate `$facet`. :D

Answer (score 7):

This is typical use case for `$group` stage in Aggregation Pipeline. You can do it like this:

- `$group` - to group all the documents by **field2**
- `$sum` - to count the number of documents for each value of **field2**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$field2",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWa2_ttnuB-)

Comment: I tried the same thing before posting the question here but the solution provided above by J.F. is correct (the solution I want). Thanks for answering NeNaD

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator and a final [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) pipeline to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { $toUpper: '$field2' },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        counts: { 
            $push: { k: '$_id', v: '$count' }
        }
    } },
    { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: '$counts' } }    
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B1M2NdIsGM1)

---